# PHP - Can I make a class that can't be instantiated except through another class?

Tags: php, class, exception, instantiation

I'm trying to have a child class from the Exception class just to handle errors and emit the proper error message given the error code.  I changed my original code and made it more simple just to illustrate my problem.

Maybe it's not possible, but I don't want the InvalidEmailException class to be instantiated by the script.  I just want it to be used by the Subscribe class if it's necessary (errors are found).  Why would I want to do this anyway? Doesn't matter I'm just trying to understand how classes work.

```
/* Child class from the parent Exception class to handle errors 
 * pertinent to users being subscribed
 */
class InvalidEmailException extends Exception{
   private $error_code;
   private $email;
   function __construct($error_code, $email){
      $this->error_code = $error_code;
      $this->email = $email;
      $this->notifyUser();
   }
   function notifyUser(){
        if($this->error_code == 2):
         echo "<p>Invalid email: <em>{$this->email}</em></p>";
      endif;
   }
}

// Initial class to subscribe a user with the try catch checks
class Subscribe{
   private $email;
   private $error_code = 0;
   function __construct($email){
      $this->email = $email;
      $this->validateEmail();
   }

   private function validateEmail(){
      try{
         if($this->email == ''):
            throw new Exception('<p>Error: empty email address.</p>');
         else:
            if($this->email == 'invalid test'){
                    $this->error_code = 2;
               throw new InvalidEmailException($this->error_code, $this->email);
            }elseif($this->error_code == 0){
               // Go to method to subscribe a user if the error code remains zero
               $this->subscribeUser();
            }
         endif;
      }catch(Exception $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();
      }
   }

   private function subscribeUser(){
      echo $this->email.' added to the database!';
   }
}

/* 
 * Script to use the Subscribe class, which would call 
 * the InvalidEmailException class if needed
 */
$email = 'invalid test'; // This could later on be used through the $_POST array to take an email from a form
$subscribe = new Subscribe($email); // Works well.
$test = new InvalidEmailException('2', 'a@b.c'); // Also works.  I want this to throw an error.
```

Comment: How do u load classes? with outoload or explicit include?

Comment: I am planning to use the autoload function later on.  This is just an example.  Forgive me for my ignorance, but it is important to know how I load the classes?

Comment: You try to emulate the friendship or assembly thingy in programming (i.e. certain classes/function which are available to only certain other functions/classes). This can be somewhat achieved in PHP with the help on how you load classes.

Comment: I think I might understand what you are saying.  So If i put the InvalidEmailException, and the Subscribe classes in seperate files, and explicitly include the InvalidEmailException class through the Subscribe class file, that way the InvalidEmailException class won't be able to be instantiated through the script (as in the example in my php code from the question).  Please clear this up for me, and is this the only way I'd be able to do it?

Comment: if u include it inside the class, it might work that way, yes, test it

Comment: Yeah I tried it; it works.  But it seems a cheap work around the problem.. it's really not professional.  I was planning to use the autoload function and just have all of my classes loaded whenever they are called upon.  I guess I'll have to keep working at this, I might have to just change the whole code around.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do not see how it trashes your use of Autoload.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot actually have any kind of class visibility other than "visible to everything ever" in PHP.  You can partially approximate it using various hacks like people have told you about, but they're pointless wastes of time because they can't enforce the visibility constraint (all are subject to trivial workarounds if a programmer wanted to violate your pseudo-constraint), and if it's not enforced you may as well just implement it at the programmer level (i.e. if you don't think it should be done, don't do it).

If your concern is with polluting the global class namespace with a very limited-usage exception class (which would be a valid concern I'd applaud you for), that's what [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) are for; a typical professional PHP 5.3 architecture would have your classes as `YourApp\Email\Subscribe` and `YourApp\Email\InvalidAddressException`.  (Which incidentally allows code inside `Subscribe` to throw a `new InvalidAddressException` without needing a `use` statement or full namespace specification.)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I needed to know for sure that this class visibility thing doesn't exist in PHP, except for 'visible to everything ever' hahaha, thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option would be to use dependency injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection. It's a bit advanced but I think it would help in the long run..

Essentially, you could create a common interface with methods getting the data you need, and make the constructor for your exception class have a parameter of type of the interface. Then have the subscribe class implement the interface, which would allow it to be passed in to the constructor of the exception.

You could also just pass in the subscribe object to the constructor of the exception class directly as the parameter and bypass the interface usage. However, the interface allows you to have multiple classes all use that interface and those common methods and they could all construct your exception class if you used that pattern. And you would also know how to interact with those classes as they use the same common design.

This doesn't completely prevent you from constructing the exception from outside the class and in the script, however you will have needed to construct the class that implements the interface first (or just the class itself, depending on which way you go), which is a good way to restrict the behavior.

Comment: Wow I'm just a novice.  I'm not sure I understood anything you wrote and I read it twice.  However, I've heard of interfaces before.. it's supposed to be the highest level? then abstract classes come in second?  Could you explain it one more time in easier terms for me.  And also.. pretty much my php code in the question can't be modified to make it work? I have to change it radically (drastically, dramatically)... right?

Comment: @Tolowe has provided you with an excellent approach. You also might want to look into the factory pattern :)

Comment: Interface is essentially like a requirement that a class has to implement certain methods. In this case you could make an interface with methods GetEmail and GetErrorCode. If you created an interface IException, then had your subscribe class implement it, you would need to define methods there. It also functions like a generic type when instantiating. So for example, you can do things like IException sub = new Subscribe();. So in the constructor for your EmailException class, you could pass parameter (IException sub), and set the values using the common methods defined in the interface.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a thought.

Use define to set a "globalized" variable.

So in your Subscribe class __construct function set a variable like `define( 'IN_USE', 1 );` and then if/when that InvalidEmailException is called just check for:

```
if( !IN_USE ) { exit; }
```

Comment: Hey that's a good idea.  It's also a cheap work around, but at least I'd still be able to use the autoload function to load all my classes as per request in my scripts.  So far I think this is the most rational answer I've gotten about this issue.  Thanks alot!

Comment: I don't know what happend, I tried to give a vote up because I think this is useful, and it gave me a message that I need 15 reputation to give votes, then it ended up giving you a vote down for this answer... weird.

Comment: @JuanVeliz: Marking this answer accepted generally means that this is the solution you wound up using that met your needs.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: It's a practical solution but for now I guess it's the best one I've seen, without having to change my code all around.  Although I would like a better way of enforcing the InvalidException so that only the Subscribe class could instantiate it.